# rename column without changing its type

Tags: sql-server

could any one help me to change the name of a column in a table without changing the type?
i am using the sql server 2008 to create table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at

[SQL SERVER – How to Rename a Column Name or Table Name](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/26/sql-server-how-to-rename-a-column-name-or-table-name/)

Comment: `sp_rename 'yourtablename.oldcolname', 'newcolname', 'COLUMN'` the `'COLUMN'` is literal.